# Can I build Spinnaker services from github zip download?

Tags: spinnaker

For the Spinnaker `echo` service, I selected the Download ZIP option from the GitHub project page.

When trying to build with gradle, the build failed with the error log:

> * Where:
>
> Build file 'E:\code\echo-master\build.gradle' line: 32
>
> * What went wrong:
>
> A problem occurred evaluating root project 'echo'.
>
> Failed to apply plugin [class 'nebula.plugin.release.ReleasePlugin']
>
> repository not found: E:\code\echo-master

The code of build.gradle on line 32:

`apply plugin: "spinnaker.project"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spinnaker.project plugin uses nebula.nebula-release which expects an initialized git repository with at least one commit. Having a fallback when no git repository is on our list of things to improve but is not there today.

```
gradlew -Prelease.version=0.1.0 <task>
```

might be a workaround today, easiest might just be

```
git init
git commit -am "initial commit"
```

Answer (score 1):

I rebuilt it with "--stacktrace", and found the detail info:

The word "repository" in error log means git repository.

Because I just downloaded the source from github with zip format.

And then I clone the source code from github, and rebuild it, and the error info was gone.